# Stack pointer error when using CCCallFuncND

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have following problem:
In cocos2dx i'm trying to run repeated action after delay:

```
cloud->runAction(CCSequence::actionOneTwo(CCDelayTime::actionWithDuration(0.3f), CCCallFuncND::actionWithTarget(cloud, callfuncND_selector(CCNode::runAction), ActionManager::getAction("bob_5"))));
```

This however causes runtime error: Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call

Does anyone know what is wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are similar questions if you search the site. Try rebuilding it first. If that doesn't work we might need to see more code

Comment: It's either mismatched calling convention or a buffer overrun clobbering the stack. More code is definitely needed.